# boto3 : validating aws_access_key and aws_secret_key

Tags: python-2.7, aws-sdk, boto3

When I run following code with wrong credentials

```
client = boto3.client(
           'iam',
           aws_access_key_id = wrong access key,
           aws_secret_access_key =  wrong secret key)
```

it does not throw an error, perhaps when I call methods on it, I get following error

```
ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the GetCredentialReport operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

Is there a way to get the same error, when creating `boto3.client` object?

Comment: The client seems only establish a connection session, not services authentication. Anyway, you should capture any exception during services call.

Comment: Isn't there any other option?

Comment: In fact, you should react on every exception. I don't see a reason to build a redundant AWS API Accesskey check.

Comment: All other service related exceptions are handled, handling this exception in service calls would be redundant.

Comment: An alternative is run a custom access test module (By the way, there is no access key in services that use AssumeRoles) to do it.